# How can I queue up an entire directory for FTP?

Tags: ftp, curl, recursive

Currently I know how to do this:

```
curl -T file.zip ftp://server.domain.com/ --user username:password
```

Which will let me do a single file. However I can't figure out how to do it for a directory. I would like to use a similar command and specify a directory instead of a single file and have it upload that directory and all contents maintaining folder structure. How is that done?

Answer (score 5):

You probably have to use something more sophisticated.  FTP itself (if I remember correctly) is not able to transfer entire directories, all it knows about is transferring a file.  Thus the client has to translate your request *"send this directory"* into a sequence of *upload this file* (possibly preceded by *make this directory*).

One such sophisticated client is [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp)), its `mirror -R` command should do the job.

([`ncftp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncftp)'s [`ncftpput`](http://www.ncftpd.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html) has a `-R` flag for this, too.)

**Edit** Of course you can also [do a recursive upload with `find` and `curl`'s `--ftp-create-dirs` flag.](http://jamesrsullivan.com/recursive-upload-with-curl).

Comment: Your find / curl link is broken, unfortunately. Better copy instead of linking to any URL that doesn't appear rock-solid.

Comment: There are no rock-solid URLs ;)  But luckily there is [the internet archive wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130526190412/http://jamesrsullivan.com/recursive-upload-with-curl).

Comment: Well, links to stack-overflow would be rock-solid, links to Google News, sourceforge mailing list archives... Anyway, the link says find -type f -exec curl -v -u myusername:mypassword --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://ftp3.ftptoyoursite.com/www.mynewwebsite.com/web/content/{} \;

Comment: Here's an SO link to the find/curl approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019890/uploading-all-of-files-in-my-local-directory-with-curl